# NotImplementedError: When subclassing the `Model` class, you should implement a `call` method

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm working on this image classification problem with [keras](/questions/tagged/keras). I'm trying to use subclassing `API's` to do almost everything. I've created my `custom` conv blocks which looks as follows:

```
class ConvBlock(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, in_features, kernel_size=(3, 3)):
        super(ConvBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv = keras.layers.Conv2D(in_features, kernel_size, padding="same")
        self.bn = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.relu = keras.activations.relu
        
    def call(self, x, training=False):
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.bn(x, training=training)
        return self.relu(x)
```

After that i've created my simple `Sequential` Model for testing which looks as follows:

```py
seq_model = keras.Sequential([
    ConvBlock(64),
    ConvBlock(128),
    ConvBlock(64),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'),
], name="seq_model")

seq_model.build((None, 96, 96, 1))
seq_model.summary()
```

So far so good, if i call `.compile()`, `.train()` and `.evaluate()` on this `seq_model` it works. The problem comes when i try to call `.compile()`, `.train()` and `.evaluate()` using my custom  `.compile()`, `.train()` and `.evaluate()`. The following code shows how i created them:

```py
class Model(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        
    # .compile()
    def compile(self, loss, optimizer, metrics):
        super().compile()
        self.loss = loss
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.custom_metrics = metrics
        
    # .fit()
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            pred = self.model(x, training=True)
            loss = self.loss(y, pred)
        
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))
        
        self.custom_metrics.update_state(y, pred)
        
        return {"loss": loss, "accuracy": self.custom_metrics.result()}
        
    # .evaluate()
    def test_step(self, data):
        x, y = data
        pred = self.model(x, training=False)
        loss = self.loss(y, pred)
        self.custom_metrics.update_state(y, pred)
        return {"loss": loss, "accuracy": self.custom_metrics.result()}
```

This is how I'm calling it.

```py
yoga_model = Model(seq_model)
yoga_model.compile(
    loss = keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
    metrics = keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name="acc")
)
yoga_model.fit(train_ds, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

Please help. A help input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your custom model with subclassed API, implement the `call` method as follows:

```
from tensorflow import keras 

class Model(keras.Model):
   def __init__:
       self.model = model
   def train_step:
   def test_step:
   def compile: 

   # implement the call method
   def call(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs):
       return self.model(inputs)
```